# Using Class.forName() in webapplication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am working on an web-application where i need to load and set a class instance before application can make sure of my functionality.
This is what i have

```
 public DefaultManager(String providerClassName)
 {
   Class<? extends Provider>classObj=(Class<? extendsProvider>) Class.forName(providerClassName);
 }
```

Since its possible that at time of application startup, class instance is not been created, moreover my manager constructor will only be called once and i need to initiate class object only once.

though this is working fine (testing with tomcat), but i am not sure if this approach is correct or there are other more efficient approach to load class (initiate  it if not )

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Something like `ServiceLoader` might be more suitable.

Comment: @chrylis: i need to load a validator instance and set it to factory, validator instance class name can be provided/configured by customer

Comment: Can you use SPI? This sounds like the sort of task it's meant for.

Comment: What about servlet init() method. You can use it, it will more stable then any other design.